# how to exclude identity column - mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "vendor_id")]Vendor v)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            eproc_db.Vendors.Add(v);
            eproc_db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        return View(v);
    }
```

The Code above gives this error "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'VENDOR' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

the value is going in as 0. looked at profiler. it's including vendor_id column also. how to exclude it?

below is the model.. Do i have to do something more?

```
 [Bind(Exclude = "vendor_id")] 
    public class Vendor
    {
        [Key]
        public decimal  vendor_id {get; set;}
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string vendor_name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string vendor_address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Tax ID")]
        public string fed_tax_id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Name")]
        public string contact_name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone")]
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks martin. I want the column to be autopopulated on insert.

Comment: Shouldn't vendor_id be an INT?

Comment: in my sql db it is numeric, i tried int and it gave me this error The 'vendor_id' property on 'Vendor' could not be set to a 'Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.

Comment: Thansk Martin. That was the issue. I made vendor_id to be int in both places and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because for vendor_id the db column was numeric and here it was decimal. I made them both decimal and the error disappeared.

Also i removed ([Bind(Exclude = "vendor_id")] from both places